# Writing a generic function with ClassTag and AnyRef constraints in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, type-bounds

Apache `SparkContext` has a method:

```
def broadcast[T: ClassTag](value: T): Broadcast[T]
```

I am trying to write a wrapper that analyses the data (for now it just tries to log the size) and calls the original method:

```
def broadcast[T: ClassTag](value: T): Broadcast[T] = {
  val sizeEst = SizeEstimator.estimate(value)
  log.debug(s"Broacasting $sizeEst bytes of data")
  sc.broadcast(value)
}
```

`org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator` expects an `AnyRef`, so I get an error. I am not particularly experienced with Scala, so `ClassTag`-s are a bit of dark magic for me.

How do I fix this snippet of code, so that both `sc.broadcast` (which expects `ClassTag`) and `SizeEstimator.estimate` (which expects an `AnyRef`) are both happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `T` as a type that extends `AnyRef`, in addition to enforcing an implicit `ClassTag`. Note that this would limit the usage of your version of `boradcast` to broadcasting only subclasses of `AnyRef`, (which are basically all non-primitives, see http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html):

```
def broadcast[T <: AnyRef : ClassTag](value: T): Broadcast[T] = {
  val sizeEst = SizeEstimator.estimate(value)
  log.debug(s"Broacasting $sizeEst bytes of data")
  sc.broadcast(value)
}

broadcast(List(1,2,3)) // compiles
broadcast("str")       // compiles
broadcast(1)           // does not compile, because Int does not extend AnyRef
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the limitation imposed by subclassing from `AnyRef`. Thanks for helping me get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Tzach Zohar's answer: since generic `T` will be boxed anyway, this is actually a rare case where `asInstanceOf` doesn't present any problems:

```
def broadcast[T: ClassTag](value: T): Broadcast[T] = {
  val sizeEst = SizeEstimator.estimate(value.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
  log.debug(s"Broacasting $sizeEst bytes of data")
  sc.broadcast(value)
}
```